# return in .then of promise - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a problem...

I created a ClientService in AngularJS (Angular) that should return a `Client` by its `ID`, but it always returns `undefined`.

```
var clients = [ ];
var API = Restangular.all('clients');

var clientsReq = API.getList(); // Call API and get Promise
var clients = clientsReq.$object; // For Displaying the Object in DOM later

this.get = {
  byId: function(id) {
    clientsReq.then(function() { // Wait for clientsReq to finish
      for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) { // Iterate over clients
        if(clients[i].id === id) { // Check if clientID matches ID
          console.log(clients[i]); // Debug - IT LOGS THE CLIENT! (Working)

          return clients[i]; // Returns undefined (Not working)
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
```

This is the Controller that calls the Service:

```
$scope.client = ClientService.get.byId('123');
console.log($scope.client); // Returns undefined
```

I already tried another implementation with $q, but that one was terrible and I don't even bother showing it here, as it was definitily wrong. I don't really know what the problem here is, but I guess it has something to do with the `clientsReq.then()`. I don't know how to wait for the Promise otherwise and I didn't found anything on Google/Stackoverflow about it.

Hope you can help me! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `return` stament before `clientsReq.then()`

```
this.get = {
  byId: function(id) {
    return clientsReq.then(function() { // Wait for clientsReq to finish
      for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) { // Iterate over clients
        if(clients[i].id === id) { // Check if clientID matches ID
          console.log(clients[i]); // Debug - IT LOGS THE CLIENT! (Working)

          return clients[i]; // Returns undefined (Not working)
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Then in your controller

```
ClientService.get.byId('123').then(function(client){

    //here use client
    $scope.client = client;
});
```

Remenber that is an async call, so you should return promises not pure values.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, it worked!
But what if I have to do multiple requests and want to return only an array? Here's an example:

`for(var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            return ClientService.get.byId(projects[i].clientId).then(function(client) {
              projects[i].client = client;

              return projects;
            });
          }`

Comment: @EinArzt read here, [angularjs promises chains](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version with `$q`

```
var clients = [];
var API = Restangular.all('clients');
var deferred = $q.defer(); // created promise object

var clientsReq = API.getList(); // Call API and get Promise
var clients = clientsReq.$object; // For Displaying the Object in DOM later

this.get = {
    byId: function(id) {
        clientsReq.then(function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                if (clients[i].id === id) {
                    console.log(clients[i]);
                    return clients[i]; // Returns undefined (Not working)
                }
            }
            deferred.resolve(clients); //this will call success method of promise and return clients.
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error); //this will call error method of promise and return error 
        });
        return deferred.promise; //this will tell the callee method that i will return something
    }
};
```

**Controller**

```
ClientService.get.byId('123').then(function(data) { //success callback called when resolve promise
    $scope.client = data;
    console.log($scope.client);
}, function(error) { //error callback called when reject promise
    console.log(error);
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.